# Preventing Bundler to install gems under the Ruby version namespace

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I install gems using Bundler to the project directory, for some reason it installs them under the Ruby version namespace, that is `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0`.

Why Bundler have such behaviour? Is there any way to prevent Bundler to install gems under the Ruby version namespace and instead to place them directly into `vendor/bundle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler does this for the same reason that rubygems does it - different Ruby distributions may not have compatible gems. For example, a gem with a C extension built against 1.9.3's ruby.h isn't going to work under 2.1.0, and neither will run under JRuby. Pure Ruby gems should work, but there is no differentiation made between pure Ruby gems and gems with native extensions in Rubygems or Bundler, so the system behaves conservatively. Additionally, some gems specify `required_ruby_version` in their gemspecs, which locks them to a particular Ruby version or versions; support of that sort of feature requires namespacing.

While you could probably monkeypatch things to get the behavior you desire, it wouldn't be very advisable, since C extensions running against the wrong Ruby version would likely result in your process segfaulting.